# jpgraph Warning (2): file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, jpgraph, open-basedir

I'm having a trouble on making the jpgraph's image work on the web. When I run it in localhost the jpgraphs works but when I uploaded it there is an error message:

> Warning (2): file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir
>   restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arialbd.ttf) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/:/usr/lib/php:/tmp) [APP/Vendor/jpgraph/jpgraph-3.5.0b1/src/jpgraph_ttf.inc.php, line 505]

and this

> Warning (2): file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir
>   restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arialbd.ttf) is
>   not within the allowed path(s): (/home/:/usr/lib/php:/tmp)
>   [APP/Vendor/jpgraph/jpgraph-3.5.0b1/src/jpgraph_ttf.inc.php, line 510]

If you guys have any questions for clarifications please don't hesitate to ask. Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an issue with your PHP configuration, not CakePHP.

From http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

> Limit the files that can be accessed by PHP to the specified directory-tree

Open your php.ini, look for the `open_basedir` line, and comment it out.

Restart webserver and you should be good to go.